# Can we pass object of a List<WebElement> to a function as a parameter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web application right now.I have used a list array to locate few objects inside a container.All I need to do is that that I have to mouse-hover to the first element and click on the same.But the mouse-hover method I have written in another class as common function.So can I use the object of the list array to pass to the mouse-hover method in any way.?

[image: SCREEN SHOT]

To Find the elements in the container .

```
 By by = By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortable']");
 List<WebElement> featureList= element.findElements(by.tagName("a"));


//Mouse-hover method

public static void moveMouseOver(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
        WebElement element = waitForElementPresent(driver, locator);
        (new Actions(driver)).moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    }


Here can I change the 'By Locator' argument to replace with List array object ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your method to:

```
public static void moveMouseOver(WebDriver driver, By locator, String...action) {
    List<WebElement> lstElements = driver.findElements(locator);
    for (WebElement webelement : lstElements){
        if (action.length > 0 && action.equalsIgnoreCase("click"))
            (new Actions(driver)).moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
        else
            (new Actions(driver)).moveToElement(element).build().perform();
}
```

In such a scenario it will work for single element also and for multiple and you won't be required to change usage in previous scenarios, though u need handle different cases in future as this one handles click only.

Comment: It restrict to insert WebElement webElements in 'MoveMouseOver method, it returns the error as "The method moveMouseOver(WebDriver, By, String) in the type ExecutionHelper is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver, By, Object[])"

Comment: how are u calling the method??

Comment: ExecutionHelper.moveMouseOver(driver,by, featureList.toArray());

Comment: u r doing it wrong buddy... it should be `ExecutionHelper.moveMouseOver(driver,by.tagName("a"), "click");` according to the way i changed the method...m not passing array to method...please go through the code once and see what is actually happening in the code...thanks...

Comment: But how can I give by.tagName("a") as a parameter .I have to use the reference of the object of WebElement where I have used to get the location of the entire container.By that reference only,I can use the tag Name("a).Please correct me if am wrong vivek

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing moveMouseOver to something like :

```
    public static void moveMouseOver(WebDriver driver, WebElement... webElements){
    if(null != webElements){
        for(WebElement webEl : webElements){
           // do something here
         }
      }
     }
```

and then call this as

```
moveMouseOver(driver, ((WebElement[])featureList.toArray()))
```

Please check for syntax errors if any as I have written this up here only and not checked in an IDE

Comment: It restrict to insert WebElement webElements in 'MoveMouseOver method, it returns the error as  "_The method moveMouseOver(WebDriver, WebElement) in the type ExecutionHelper is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver, Object[]) Custom Components_"